# Basic Login ajax-php, (XMLHttpRequest). Sometimes work, sometimes doesn't

Tags: javascript, php, authentication, xmlhttprequest

I'm just coming back to web developing. In my first steps, I'm working on a basic log in which is turning me crazy. Here we go:

1. Js code just react to the login button, sending id and password.
2. PHP code checks the data received on the ddbb and returns a code error if there is a mismatch, or a URL to redirect if the login was successfully.
3. Js get the answer from php and then displays a message to the user or just redirects to the personal area.

Despite the rudimentary off the code and the design mistakes ( just trying to make it run), many times it works successfully, but many other it didn't get more than a 1 (server connection ok) on the onreadystatechange. So I need to ask, someone know what could it be?

Why onreadystatechange keeps it stuck on first step sometimes ? What am I missing?

Thanks a lot.

(once I get this one working, I will try again with other tools, minding jQuery instead basic js and jwt instead sessions, but this will be next one. I'll accept suggestions )

JavaScript code:

```
var boton = document.getElementById("boton");
boton.addEventListener('click', validarLogIn);

function validarLogIn()
{
    var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre");
    var contraseña = document.getElementById("contraseña");
    var parametros="Nombre="+nombre.value+"&Contraseña="+contraseña.value;
    http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http_request.onreadystatechange = resultadoLogIn;
    http_request.open("POST", "../php/validarLogin.php");
    http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http_request.send(parametros);
}

function resultadoLogIn()
{
    var respuesta=http_request.responseText;
    if (http_request.readyState == 4){
        if (http_request.status == 200){
            if(respuesta==1){
                    alert("Contraseña incorrecta.");
                }else if(respuesta==2){
                        alert("Usuario no encontrado.");
                    }else{
                        window.location=respuesta; 
                    }
            }else{
                alert('Hubo problemas con la petición.');
            }
        }
}
```

PHP code

```
$nombre =$_POST['Nombre'];
$contraseña =$_POST ['Contraseña'];
require_once 'DatosBBDD.php';
$consultaBbdd="SELECT ID,CONTRASEÑA FROM usuarios WHERE ID ='".$nombre."'";
$urlRedireccion="../php/vistaGeneral.php";

$link = mysqli_connect($ip,$usuarioBbdd,$contrasenaBbdd);
mysqli_select_db($link, $nombreBbdd);
$result = mysqli_query($link,$consultaBbdd);
mysqli_data_seek ($result, 0);
$extraido= mysqli_fetch_array($result);
mysqli_close($link);

$nombreV=false;
$contraseñaV=false;

if(isset($extraido['ID'])&&isset($extraido['CONTRASEÑA'])){ 
    if ($extraido['ID']==$nombre){$nombreV=true;}
    if ($extraido['CONTRASEÑA']==$contraseña){$contraseñaV=true;}
}

if($nombreV){
    if($contraseñaV){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['idUsuario']=$nombre;
        echo $urlRedireccion;
    }else{echo "1";}
}else{echo "2";}
```

Comment: Your code is wide open to [SQL Injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attack due to the use of raw user supplied data being used directly in the sql. To help mitigate this threat you should always use [Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). A really useful guide, with plenty of example code, built by [Your Common Sense](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285587/your-common-sense) is [PHP Delusions](https://phpdelusions.net/)

Comment: I would try to remove the "ñ" to rule out any errors. Have you checked your error.log?

Comment: Thanks, @ProfessorAbronsius, ill check it.

Comment: Yes, but nothing shows at php logs file. Ill rewrite it without 'ñ'.Thanks @AleBuo

Comment: Some other points perhaps worth noting in addition to the use of accents within the HTML and Javascript as previously noted.  Unless the `query`/`execute` methods for the database are within `require_once'ConsultaBBDD.php';` then it does not appear that the sql query is run at all. Have you `hashed` the user's password using `password_hash` and do you  subsequently check the password supplied at logon is correct using `password_verify`?

Comment: Yes, they was in ConsultaBBDD.php. I already edited the post to include that code . The variables IP, user, pasw and the db name are contained on the other include, DatosBBDD.php.

Im afraid i didnt hashed the password, I'll do nextly. Thanks, @ProfessorAbronsius